# checking json array with postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have an JSONB array in postgres in the follow format.

```
{
   "id" : 22323,
   "details" : [
                        {
                            "status" : "stage1",
                             "timestamp" : "2017-09-89"
                         },
                        {
                            "status" : "stage2",
                             "timestamp" : "2017-09-89"
                         }
                        ]
    }
```

I need to get the timestamp at stage2, how do I select the particular status's timestamp in postgresql ?

Comment: if index of "details" always same as `"status": "stageVALUE`, you can just `use ->element`, but if not - you need to iterate over elements of array with `json_array_elements`

Comment: I tried `select (json_column ->> 'details')::json ->> status from table` and it didn't work. I got empty results.

Comment: because you dont work with array here. - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if index of "details" always same as "status": "stageVALUE, you can just use ->element, but if not - you need to iterate over elements of array with json_array_elements, like here:

```
t=# with b as (with v as (select '{
   "id" : 22323,
   "details" : [
                        {
                            "status" : "stage1",
                             "timestamp" : "2017-09-89"
                         },
                        {
                            "status" : "stage2",
                             "timestamp" : "2017-09-89"
                         }
                        ]
    }'::json j)
select json_array_elements(j->'details') j from v)
select j->>'timestamp' from b where j->>'status' = 'stage2'
;
  ?column?
------------
 2017-09-89
(1 row)
```

and if stage2 is always second array element, the cheaper:

```
t=# with v as (select '{
   "id" : 22323,
   "details" : [
                        {
                            "status" : "stage1",
                             "timestamp" : "2017-09-89"
                         },
                        {
                            "status" : "stage2",
                             "timestamp" : "2017-09-89"
                         }
                        ]
    }'::json j)
select j->'details'->1->>'timestamp' from v;
  ?column?
------------
 2017-09-89
(1 row)
```

I use index 1 cos arrays are indexed from 0

Comment: Ah nice but the position in the JSON can unfortunately change, there fore, I tried out option 1. I made the query as 
`with x as (select jsonb_array_elements(tracking_info -> 'details') j from tracking_data) select x ->> 'status' from x;`I get `ERROR:  operator does not exist: record ->> unknown`

Comment: Which is pretty weird and I cannot convert record to json either

Comment: oh that is because you showed different code :) please create another question with your plpgslq code

Comment: Nevermind, found out the mistake, thanks :) It should be using j